# Sklearn kNN usage with a user defined metric

Tags: python, knn

Currently I'm doing a project which may require using a kNN algorithm to find the  top k nearest neighbors for a given point, say P. im using python, sklearn package to do the job, but our predefined metric is not one of those default metrics. so I have to use the user defined metric, from the documents of sklearn, which can be find [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.get_params) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html).

It seems that the latest version of sklearn kNN support the user defined metric, but i cant find how to use it:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
from sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree import BallTree
BallTree.valid_metrics
```

say i have defined a metric called mydist=max(x-y), then use DistanceMetric.get_metric to make it a DistanceMetric object:

```
dt=DistanceMetric.get_metric('pyfunc',func=mydist)
```

from the document, the line should looks like this

```
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='auto',metric='pyfunc').fit(A)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(A)
```

but where can i put the `dt` in? Thanks

Comment: the reason `nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='auto',metric='pyfunc').fit(A)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(A)` not working even i put `func=mydist` in there is because the parameter `algorithm=auto` not accepting user defined metrics, neither `algorithm=kd_tree` or `algorithm=brute`. Only the `algorithm=ball_tree` accepts

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You pass a metric as `metric` param, and additional metric arguments as keyword paramethers to NN constructor:

```
>>> def mydist(x, y):
...     return np.sum((x-y)**2)
...
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])

>>> nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='ball_tree',
...            metric='pyfunc', func=mydist)
>>> nbrs.fit(X)
NearestNeighbors(algorithm='ball_tree', leaf_size=30, metric='pyfunc',
         n_neighbors=4, radius=1.0)
>>> nbrs.kneighbors(X)
(array([[  0.,   1.,   5.,   8.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2.,  13.],
       [  0.,   2.,   5.,  25.],
       [  0.,   1.,   5.,   8.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2.,  13.],
       [  0.,   2.,   5.,  25.]]), array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 0, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 0],
       [4, 3, 5, 0],
       [5, 4, 3, 0]]))
```

Comment: I am using scikit-learn 0.18.dev0 version and I get the following error - `_init_params() got an unexpected keyword argument 'func'`

Comment: @ShishirPandey You could check the following commit, https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/ad751a3b6996a4c209c1a243d396aa6930d4acc4, NN signature has been changed. I guess you could just pass mydist directly as "metric" argument

Comment: how can I define custom metric for sparse vectors? Using this method I get:
`ValueError: metric 'pyfunc' not valid for sparse input`

Answer (score 22):

A small addition to the previous answer. How to use a user defined metric that takes **additional arguments**.

```
>>> def mydist(x, y, **kwargs):
...     return np.sum((x-y)**kwargs["metric_params"]["power"])
...
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>> Y = np.array([-1, -1, -2, 1, 1, 2])
>>> nbrs = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='ball_tree',
...            metric=mydist, metric_params={"power": 2})
>>> nbrs.fit(X, Y)
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='ball_tree', leaf_size=30,                                                                                                                                                          
       metric=<function mydist at 0x7fd259c9cf50>, n_neighbors=4, p=2,
       weights='uniform')
>>> nbrs.kneighbors(X)
(array([[  0.,   1.,   5.,   8.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2.,  13.],
       [  0.,   2.,   5.,  25.],
       [  0.,   1.,   5.,   8.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2.,  13.],
       [  0.,   2.,   5.,  25.]]),
 array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 0, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 0],
       [4, 3, 5, 0],
       [5, 4, 3, 0]]))
```

Comment: I actually think that in the function it needs to be kwargs["power"], not kwargs["metric_params"]["power"]  . At least that's the behaviour I observe with sklearn '0.16.1'

Comment: @benbo you are right: I fixed the code and added a little comment (I edited the post by Mahmoud).

Answer (score 0):

Using KNeighborsRegressor() worked only by setting algorithm='brute' when trying to use a user defined metric.

Otherwise fit() works but predict() fails with error 'returned NULL without setting an error' when using JupyterLab, or 'SystemError: error return without exception set' when using Google Colab