# How to allow sklearn K Nearest Neighbors to take custom distance metric?

Tags: scikit-learn, distance, nearest-neighbor, udf

I have a custom distance metric that I need to use for `KNN`, `K Nearest Neighbors`.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052509/sklearn-knn-usage-with-a-user-defined-metric), but I cannot get it to work for some reason.

I would assume that the distance metric is supposed to take two vectors/arrays of the same length, as I have written below:

```
import sklearn 
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def d(a,b,L):
    # Inputs: a and b are rows from a data matrix   
    return a+b+2+L

knn=NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1,
                 algorithm='auto',
                 metric='pyfunc',
                 func=lambda a,b: d(a,b,L)
                 )


X=pd.DataFrame({'b':[0,3,2],'c':[1.0,4.3,2.2]})
knn.fit(X)
```

However, when I call: `knn.kneighbors()`, it doesn't seem to like the custom function.  Here is the bottom of the error stack:

```
ValueError: Unknown metric pyfunc. Valid metrics are ['euclidean', 'l2', 'l1', 'manhattan', 'cityblock', 'braycurtis', 'canberra', 'chebyshev', 'correlation', 'cosine', 'dice', 'hamming', 'jaccard', 'kulsinski', 'mahalanobis', 'matching', 'minkowski', 'rogerstanimoto', 'russellrao', 'seuclidean', 'sokalmichener', 'sokalsneath', 'sqeuclidean', 'yule', 'wminkowski'], or 'precomputed', or a callable
```

However, I see the exact same in the question I cited.  Any ideas on how to make this work on `sklearn version 0.14`?  I'm not aware of any differences in the versions.

Thanks.

Comment: also your distance function is no good, it will return a vector, wheras it needs to return a single value

Answer (score 14):

[The documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors) is actually pretty clear on the use of the metric argument:

> metric : string or callable, default ‘minkowski’
>
> metric to use for distance computation. Any metric from scikit-learn or scipy.spatial.distance can be used.
>
> If metric is a callable function, it is called on each pair of instances (rows) and the resulting value recorded. The callable should
>   take two arrays as input and return one value indicating the distance
>   between them. This works for Scipy’s metrics, but is less efficient
>   than passing the metric name as a string.

Thus (as also per the error message), `metric` should be a *callable*, not a string. And it should accept two arguments (arrays), and return one. Which is your `lambda` function.

Thus, your code can be simplified to:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def d(a,b,L):
    return a+b+2+L

knn=NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1,
                 algorithm='auto',
                 metric=lambda a,b: d(a,b,L)
                 )
X=pd.DataFrame({'b':[0,3,2],'c':[1.0,4.3,2.2]})
knn.fit(X)
```

Comment: Thank you. The documentation I saw was [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html), neither of which are as detailed as what you cited.  Thank you.

Comment: I used the following code. Its giving me pickling error.Can you help me with this? My code :

def dist2(a,b):
    return jaccard(a,b)

knnobj = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=6, algorithm='auto',metric=lambda a,b: dist2(a,b)).fit(my_Data)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed