# How to use a user defined metric for nearest neighbors in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, distance, metrics, nearest-neighbor

I am using scikit-learn 0.18.dev0. I know exactly the same question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052509/sklearn-knn-usage-with-a-user-defined-metric). I tried the answer presented there, I am getting the following error

```
>>> def mydist(x, y):
...     return np.sum((x-y)**2)
...
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3,   2]])

>>> nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='ball_tree',
...            metric='pyfunc', func=mydist)
```

Error message 
`_init_params() got an unexpected keyword argument 'func'`

It looks like this option has been removed. How can I use a user defined matrix in `sklearn.neighbors`?

Answer (score 6):

The proper keyword is `metric`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

def mydist(x, y):
    return np.sum((x-y)**2)

nn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='ball_tree', metric=myfunc)

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3,   2]])
nn.fit(X)
```

This is also mentioned in the docstring in the development version: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/86b1ba72771718acbd1e07fbdc5caaf65ae65440/sklearn/neighbors/unsupervised.py#L48