# Is there a weighted metric in KNeighborsClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to see if I can modify the weight of the metric in KNeighborsClassifier. The L2 Euclidean metric works like this :

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([6,5,4])

def d(x,y)=
  sqrt((x[0]-y[0])^2 + (x[1]-y[1])^2 + (x[2]-y[2])^2)
```

But what if I want to add weighting, say `[1,2,3]` to the L2 metric? For example,

```
w = np.array([1,2,3])
def d2(x,y)=
  sqrt(w[0]*(x[0]-y[0])^2 + w[1]*(x[1]-y[1])^2 + w[2]*(x[2]-y[2])^2)
```

Is there anything I can do with the metric or metric_params in

```
KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, weights='uniform', p=2, metric='minkowski', metric_params=None, **kwargs)
```

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to pass your own metric using the `metric` when calling `KNeighborsClassifier`

Comment: you can pass d2(youre distance function) in `metric` parameter see reference answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520524/6075699) - `KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, weights='uniform', p=2, metric=d2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a user defined metric for nearest neighbors in scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518403/how-to-use-a-user-defined-metric-for-nearest-neighbors-in-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes there is something.**

In [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) there is an argument

```
> metric_params--- dict, optional (default = None) Additional keyword arguments for the metric function.
```

For sklearn l2 you Can **not** specify weights, but for some other metrics or your own version you can