# How to use Dynamic Time warping with kNN in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, classification, knn

I have a time-series dataset with two lables (`0` and `1`). I am using *Dynamic Time Warping (DTW)* as a similarity measure for classification using k-nearest neighbour (kNN) as described in these two wonderful blog posts:

- https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/markdregan/K-Nearest-Neighbors-with-Dynamic-Time-Warping/blob/master/K_Nearest_Neighbor_Dynamic_Time_Warping.ipynb
- http://alexminnaar.com/2014/04/16/Time-Series-Classification-and-Clustering-with-Python.html

  ```
  Arguments
  ---------
  n_neighbors : int, optional (default = 5)
      Number of neighbors to use by default for KNN

  max_warping_window : int, optional (default = infinity)
      Maximum warping window allowed by the DTW dynamic
      programming function

  subsample_step : int, optional (default = 1)
      Step size for the timeseries array. By setting subsample_step = 2,
      the timeseries length will be reduced by 50% because every second
      item is skipped. Implemented by x[:, ::subsample_step]
  """

  def __init__(self, n_neighbors=5, max_warping_window=10000, subsample_step=1):
      self.n_neighbors = n_neighbors
      self.max_warping_window = max_warping_window
      self.subsample_step = subsample_step

  def fit(self, x, l):
      """Fit the model using x as training data and l as class labels

      Arguments
      ---------
      x : array of shape [n_samples, n_timepoints]
          Training data set for input into KNN classifer

      l : array of shape [n_samples]
          Training labels for input into KNN classifier
      """

      self.x = x
      self.l = l

  def _dtw_distance(self, ts_a, ts_b, d = lambda x,y: abs(x-y)):
      """Returns the DTW similarity distance between two 2-D
      timeseries numpy arrays.

      Arguments
      ---------
      ts_a, ts_b : array of shape [n_samples, n_timepoints]
          Two arrays containing n_samples of timeseries data
          whose DTW distance between each sample of A and B
          will be compared

      d : DistanceMetric object (default = abs(x-y))
          the distance measure used for A_i - B_j in the
          DTW dynamic programming function

      Returns
      -------
      DTW distance between A and B
      """

      # Create cost matrix via broadcasting with large int
      ts_a, ts_b = np.array(ts_a), np.array(ts_b)
      M, N = len(ts_a), len(ts_b)
      cost = sys.maxint * np.ones((M, N))

      # Initialize the first row and column
      cost[0, 0] = d(ts_a[0], ts_b[0])
      for i in xrange(1, M):
          cost[i, 0] = cost[i-1, 0] + d(ts_a[i], ts_b[0])

      for j in xrange(1, N):
          cost[0, j] = cost[0, j-1] + d(ts_a[0], ts_b[j])

      # Populate rest of cost matrix within window
      for i in xrange(1, M):
          for j in xrange(max(1, i - self.max_warping_window),
                          min(N, i + self.max_warping_window)):
              choices = cost[i - 1, j - 1], cost[i, j-1], cost[i-1, j]
              cost[i, j] = min(choices) + d(ts_a[i], ts_b[j])

      # Return DTW distance given window 
      return cost[-1, -1]

  def _dist_matrix(self, x, y):
      """Computes the M x N distance matrix between the training
      dataset and testing dataset (y) using the DTW distance measure

      Arguments
      ---------
      x : array of shape [n_samples, n_timepoints]

      y : array of shape [n_samples, n_timepoints]

      Returns
      -------
      Distance matrix between each item of x and y with
          shape [training_n_samples, testing_n_samples]
      """

      # Compute the distance matrix        
      dm_count = 0

      # Compute condensed distance matrix (upper triangle) of pairwise dtw distances
      # when x and y are the same array
      if(np.array_equal(x, y)):
          x_s = np.shape(x)
          dm = np.zeros((x_s[0] * (x_s[0] - 1)) // 2, dtype=np.double)

          p = ProgressBar(shape(dm)[0])

          for i in xrange(0, x_s[0] - 1):
              for j in xrange(i + 1, x_s[0]):
                  dm[dm_count] = self._dtw_distance(x[i, ::self.subsample_step],
                                                    y[j, ::self.subsample_step])

                  dm_count += 1
                  p.animate(dm_count)

          # Convert to squareform
          dm = squareform(dm)
          return dm

      # Compute full distance matrix of dtw distnces between x and y
      else:
          x_s = np.shape(x)
          y_s = np.shape(y)
          dm = np.zeros((x_s[0], y_s[0])) 
          dm_size = x_s[0]*y_s[0]

          p = ProgressBar(dm_size)

          for i in xrange(0, x_s[0]):
              for j in xrange(0, y_s[0]):
                  dm[i, j] = self._dtw_distance(x[i, ::self.subsample_step],
                                                y[j, ::self.subsample_step])
                  # Update progress bar
                  dm_count += 1
                  p.animate(dm_count)

          return dm

  def predict(self, x):
      """Predict the class labels or probability estimates for 
      the provided data

      Arguments
      ---------
        x : array of shape [n_samples, n_timepoints]
            Array containing the testing data set to be classified

      Returns
      -------
        2 arrays representing:
            (1) the predicted class labels 
            (2) the knn label count probability
      """

      dm = self._dist_matrix(x, self.x)

      # Identify the k nearest neighbors
      knn_idx = dm.argsort()[:, :self.n_neighbors]

      # Identify k nearest labels
      knn_labels = self.l[knn_idx]

      # Model Label
      mode_data = mode(knn_labels, axis=1)
      mode_label = mode_data[0]
      mode_proba = mode_data[1]/self.n_neighbors

      return mode_label.ravel(), mode_proba.ravel()
  ```

However, for classification with kNN the two posts use their own kNN algorithms.

I want to use sklearn's options such as `gridsearchcv` in my classification. Therefore, I would like to know how I can use Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) with sklearn kNN.

**Note: I am not limited to `sklearn` and happy to receive answers in other libraries as well**

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: The `metric` argument of KNN in sklearn looks for an instance of the `DistanceMetric` class, found here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html You will see this class allows user-defined metrics. A usage example can be found here (although a different version of sklearn is used, so watch out, but still applicable) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052509/sklearn-knn-usage-with-a-user-defined-metric

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a custom metric for KNN. 
Therefore you only need to implement DTW yourself (or use/adapt any existing DTW implementation in python) [[gist of this code]](https://gist.github.com/nikolasrieble/8bd3a83e14c0b2fa66bfa2ddd8828717).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

#toy dataset 
X = np.random.random((100,10))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, (100))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

#custom metric
def DTW(a, b):   
    an = a.size
    bn = b.size
    pointwise_distance = distance.cdist(a.reshape(-1,1),b.reshape(-1,1))
    cumdist = np.matrix(np.ones((an+1,bn+1)) * np.inf)
    cumdist[0,0] = 0

    for ai in range(an):
        for bi in range(bn):
            minimum_cost = np.min([cumdist[ai, bi+1],
                                   cumdist[ai+1, bi],
                                   cumdist[ai, bi]])
            cumdist[ai+1, bi+1] = pointwise_distance[ai,bi] + minimum_cost

    return cumdist[an, bn]

#train
parameters = {'n_neighbors':[2, 4, 8]}
clf = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(metric=DTW), parameters, cv=3, verbose=1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)



#evaluate
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Which yields

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 3 candidates, totalling 9 fits        

[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:   29.0s finished

                         precision    recall  f1-score   support

                      0       0.57      0.89      0.70        18
                      1       0.60      0.20      0.30        15

            avg / total       0.58      0.58      0.52        33
```

Comment: How to use this solution for multi feature time series.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70227646/how-to-use-dtw-knn-for-time-series-classification-with-input-sequence-containing

Comment: @user2783767 In the sample code I provided, I am using https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html which already works on multidimensional input. Note: I did not yet try out whether this works with multidimensional data myself, but I do not see why it should not.

Comment: What if the trained samples had all different lengths as it is often the case with time series?

Comment: @Irazza I do not understand your question. DTW is built to handle time series with different length. That is one of the major advantages over Euclidean Distance.

Answer (score 4):

Use [dtaidistance](https://dtaidistance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This is the simplified pipeline of what I'm using in order to find the best fit for all windows with lengths between 1 and 20:

```
from dtaidistance import dtw
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

def knn(trainX,trainY,testX,testY,w):
    predictions = np.zeros(len(testX))

    for testSampleIndex,testSample in enumerate(testX):
        minimumDistance = float('inf')
        for trainingSampleIndex, trainingSample in enumerate(trainX):
            distanceBetweenTestAndTrainingAScan = dtw.distance(testSample,trainingSample,use_c=True,window=w,max_dist=minimumDistance)
            if (distanceBetweenTestAndTrainingAScan < minimumDistance):
                minimumDistance = distanceBetweenTestAndTrainingAScan
                predictions[testSampleIndex] = trainY[trainingSampleIndex]

    return [testY,predictions]

def DTWForCurrentDataSet(testX,testY,trainX,trainY,testDataSetID):
    testDataSetBestF1Score = -float("inf")
    testDataSetBestPredictions = []
    for w in range(1,21):
        [testY,predictions] = knn(trainX,trainY,testX,testY,w)

        microF1Score = f1_score(testY, predictions, average='micro')
        if (microF1Score > testDataSetBestF1Score):
            testDataSetBestF1Score = microF1Score
            testDataSetBestPredictions = predictions
    return testDataSetBestPredictions

def runDTW(database):
    for testDataSetID in database:
        [testX,testY,trainX,trainY,patientIDsForTraining] = createTestingAndTrainingSets(database,testDataSetID)
        testDataSetBestPredictions = DTWForCurrentDataSet(testX,testY,trainX,trainY,testDataSetID)
```

Comment: Hi, I am using `dtaidistance` as you have suggested in this question. However I got the following issue while using the library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211066/how-to-get-distance-matrix-using-dynamic-time-wraping please let me know your thoughts, thank you :)

Comment: How to use this solution for multi feature time series. stackoverflow.com/questions/70227646

Answer (score 3):

The tslearn library has [DTW](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gen_modules/metrics/tslearn.metrics.dtw.html#tslearn.metrics.dtw) metric and can be used with sklearn.

```
from tslearn.metrics import dtw
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10, metric=dtw)
```

Comment: By far the easiest

Comment: In this case which kind of structure I need to use for the training phase (e.g. clf.fit(x, y))? A list of np.array of different length ? More simply a list of lists ? In both cases python throws a value error.